# Bind multiple events to same function

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, jquery-on, touch-event

How can I bind mutiple events to the same function. I want click and touchstart to do the same. And then I want a second function for mouseover. I would like to use this kind of setup:

```
    $(document).on({
        click: function (event) {
        // I want this: click, touchstart: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // do something         
        },
        mouseover: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // do something         
        }
    }, '.link');
```

Comment: Try jQuery`s `.on()` . REF: http://api.jquery.com/on/ .**Note:this is supported on v1.7  and above**

Comment: @dreamweiver - the code shown is already using `.on()`.

Comment: ha ha ha, my bad:) in that case, the author should have spent some time in reading the actual definition of `.on()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the events in one `.on()` with space:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    // this will be called on click as well as touchstart
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't call an external function instead:

```
function myExternalFunction (event) {
    // do stuff
}

$(document).on({
    click: myExternalFunction,
    mouseover: myExternalFunction
}, '.link');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the `.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) (and confirmed via a quick look at the `.on()` implementation) you could do this:

```
$(document).on({
    "click touchstart" : function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do something         
    },
    mouseover: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do something         
    }
}, '.link');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XzkTm/