# Multiple event listeners?

Tags: jquery, events

I have the below code setup to use both 'change' and 'input' event listeners on my variable seekbar. As you can see they are exact duplicates, so I'm wondering how to merge the 2 event listeners into a single function?

```
 // Event listener for the seek bar
 seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Calculate the new time
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

    // Update the video time
    video.currentTime = time;
});

// Event listener for the seek bar
seekBar.addEventListener("input", function() {
    // Calculate the new time
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

    // Update the video time
    video.currentTime = time;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind multiple events to same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425311/bind-multiple-events-to-same-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the callback function as a named function and give reference instead of duplicating.

```
function seek() {
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
    video.currentTime = time;
}

seekBar.addEventListener("change", seek);
seekBar.addEventListener("input", seek);
```

Or do something like this :

```
['change', 'input'].forEach(function(event){
   seekBar.addEventListener(event, seek);
});
```

---

In jQuery you can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with space separated multiple events.

```
$(seekBar).on('input change', function() {
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
    video.currentTime = time;
})
```